# Rails two has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

There are two different types of Users: photographers and people who are looking for a photographer (both Users though). Normal users can choose a group of photographers and post "briefs" to that group. What's the best model association setup?

```
Brief
  belongs_to :user # a user looking for a photographer
  has_many :photographers, :class_name => "User", :through => :jobs # photographers who have been selected to participate in this brief

User
  has_many :briefs
  has_many :jobs, :class_name => "Brief", :through => :jobs
```

Answer (score 0):

Look up Single Table Inheritance for the users / photographers / clients.

Btw, "has_many :jobs, :through => :jobs" isn't going to help you.

I think you want this:

```
Class Person < User
  has_many :briefs, :foreign_key => "poster_id"
end

Class Photographer < User
 has_many :briefs, :foreign_key => "photographer_id"
end
```

Comment: Hope you can work out what briefs looks like, just ask otherwise. If I've misunderstood a part just say.